# How to give an unique output in powershell

Tags: powershell, output, unique

I am trying to give an output `"unique"`. What do I have to change in this code ?

```
If ($append -Eq "y")
{
    $objRights | Export-Csv -Path $outRightsFile -Delimiter ";" -Append -NoTypeInformation
} 
Else
{
    $objRights | Export-Csv -Path $outRightsFile -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: What do you trying to do?

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: Did you meant "unique" by : How to keep only one Export-CSv that cover both situation ? If not, please clarify your question. If yes, you can replace your whole code sample by the following line : 

    $objRights | Export-Csv -Path $outRightsFile -Append:($append -Eq "y")  -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation

Answer (score 3):

The [`Select-Object` CmdLet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) has an `-Unique` parameter.

Ruthlessly stolen example from the docs:

```
"a","b","c","a","a","a" | Select-Object -Unique

a
b
c
```

Therefore your code could simply become:

```
$objRights |
    Select-Object -Unique |
    Export-Csv -Path $outRightsFile -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: gvee thank you so much! this was what I was looking for. :D You understood the question. And I tried it but it only gives one row as an output. Before I had many different rows... do you have any idea?

Comment: @Heidy - were all of the rows duplicates before? `;-)` Is it exporting all of the columns you required? You may need to be more explicit with the `Select-Object` cmdlet, passing in a list of the properties you wish to export e.g. `Select-Object Username, Email, Department -Unique`

Comment: Select-Object Username -Unique            worked! Thank you Gvee :)))